# Setting up dual monitors on MacBook Pro with Retina

Tags: display, macbook-pro, vga-adapter

I just got my **MacBook Pro with Retina** yesterday and I bought a **Mini DisplayPort to VGA Adapter** to setup dual monitor, it worked fine.

Today I tried to connect Retina with my external monitor, I tried again and again.

My Macbook Pro just can't detect the monitor why?

Comment: Try to reboot your rMBP first.

Comment: I've tried reboot and several methods yesterday, it couldn't work.
Today I boot my RMBP and it works!
I don't know what's happening..., whatever it works fine right now!
thanks for helping:)

Comment: What is model of your monitor? Why VGA and not a digital connection? Is it a CRT?